# How to install a Python 3 package, system wide, using pip?

Tags: python-3.x, pip

I don't want to use virtualenv. I want to install system wide, as root.

How do I make pip install a package for Python 3?

If I simply do

```
pip install <package name>
```

It installs it for Python 2.

This is specifically what happens for chatterbot when I do:

```
pip install chatterbot
```

As root.

How do I make it install chatterbot for Python 3?

Comment: `pip` is for Python 2, `pip3` is for Python 3

Comment: @ForceBru I have installed python3-pip, yet I have no "pip3".

Comment: Alternatively you can run `python3 -m pip <your arguments>`. That's the same thing as running `pip3`.

Comment: `ls -lAF /usr/local/bin/pip3* /usr/bin/pip3*`

Answer (score 2):

### Install pip for python3

For begin you must install pip for python3 with the command in linux :

```
sudo apt-get install python3-pip
```

### Usage

After you have just to use this command for your package (Warning : The package may not exist for python3 for the moment)

```
pip3 install <package name>
```

Comment: Thanks, I have installed python3-pip, but I have no pip3 binary.

Comment: When you install python3-pip you have : "bash : pip3 : command not found" ?
If it that try to run this command with sudo or reboot your computer, because normally you must have this command.

Comment: I don't have pip3 as root nor as a normal user. I installed python3-pip as root, obviously. The only thing *pip3* I have after installing it is: /usr/share/man/man1/pip3.1.gz I have tried rebooting.

Comment: I have not any idea what you don't have the command pip3.
Sorry ^^"